# positioning the activity circle inside the UIActivityIndicator by bringing it little down

Tags: ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am customising the **UIActivityIndicatorView**.

After adding the background color and textlabel my activity indicator looks like this :

[image]

But now I want to move the circle little down to give some gap between the text 'Loading' and circle. I am expecting it to look like this :

[image]

How to do this?

code :

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60)];
    activity.layer.cornerRadius=5;
    [activity startAnimating];
    activity.color=[UIColor whiteColor];
    activity.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
    [activity setCenter:CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/2)];
    [activityBackView addSubview:activity];

    UILabel *loading=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -3, 60, 25)];
    loading.text=@"Loading...";
    loading.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:12];
    loading.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    loading.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    loading.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [activity addSubview:loading];
```

Comment: will you please able to show code  . . .

Comment: By customizing, do you mean you're subclassing it, or modifying it somehow after it's been instantiated?

Comment: I am modifying it after it has been created. if there is a way to subclass it , then its also welcome.